# Java : Using ExecutorService for httpRequests

Tags: java, multithreading, http

I have a Web Application where i receive a  lot(100K per hour) of http requests. I do not have any concerns regarding the Servlet container thread handling.

However, for each such web request, I would like to further multithread the process so that i can increase the response time of each request.

I would like to use ExecutorService , initialize newFixedThreadPool for every such request and use future object to stitch back the response from all concurrent threads(for each request) and finally submit the response back to the client.

The advantage i see with this approach is my response time is drastically reduced as multiple threads are acting upon the same request rather than a single thread.

Please suggest if this is the right way?

Comment: This is probably not needed.  The bottle neck is likely to be maybe DB - are you using DBCP? or other loading of resources.  Do not try to optimize before you know what to optimize.

Comment: I am using database connection pooling. The only reason why i would like to optimize is to decrease the response time with parallel execution.

Comment: Can you give a bit more background on which technos you are using ? It's a bit difficult to help without bacground.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, OP does not mention any DB !

Comment: @LouisF. Really, I can see his comment saying `I am using database connection pooling.`

Comment: Each Request takes around 400 ms. Consider a request xml which has multiple child elements. I would like to take each child element and process separately via separate threads in the same request. The Response time is directly proportional to the number of child elements.Now when i invoke one thread per child element, i see all the responses within 400 ms irrespective of number of child elements.

Comment: Isn't the Servlet Container doing the thread handling for you??? For example, in Tomcat you can specify the number of simultanious connections that are possible, and Tomcat will create a Thread pool and handle all this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please suggest, is this the right way?

Your server is handling almost 30 requests per second on average.  How long does each request take to complete?  How much CPU time does each request use?  What percent of the available CPU is that? How much time does each request spent waiting for I/O, or waiting to talk to other services (e.g., a database)?  If there's significant compute time, what is the computation?  Does it make sense to parallelize it?

Nobody can say whether multi-threading is "the right way" without knowing the answers to those questions.

---

Edit:  You say each request takes 400ms.  OK, if they're coming in at a steady 100K per hour pace, that means that at any given instant, your server will be processing about eleven simultaneous requests.

That's useful information, but maybe not as useful as the other questions that I asked:  How much CPU time does each request use?  What percent of the available CPU is that?  How much time does it spend waiting for I/O?  What percent of the available I/O bandwidth is that?

You say that each request is composed of several independent parts.

Maybe it will shorten the overall response time if you change the code to handle each part in a separate thread, and maybe it won't.  There's just not enough information here---information about the hardware platform, information about your application, information about the resources that it uses---to predict the outcome.

Have you tried it?

You make it sound like you already know how to make the change.  You make it sound like it won't be difficult.  Sometimes, doing an experiment is the easiest way to find out.

Comment: Each Request takes around 400 ms. Consider a request xml which has multiple child elements. I would like to take each child element and process separately via separate threads in the same request. The Response time is directly proportional to the number of child elements.Now when i invoke one thread per child element, i see all the responses within 400 ms irrespective of number of child elements.

Comment: @sumankumar - the only way to _know_ is to try.  why not just try it and find out?  all the hypothesis that we can make here doesn't ultimately mean anything for your specific case.

Comment: Sure. Let me try and keep you update about the outcome. Thanks fr your help